# Changing image of sprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I've got a pause button in my game, in fact it is just a CCSprite:

```
_pauseButton = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pauseButton.png"] retain];
_pauseButton.position = ccp(_winSize.width * 0.92, _winSize.height * 0.1);
[self addChild:_pauseButton];
```

And on press I wanna pause the game and switch pausebutton's image to @"playButton.png".

I know 2 ways for doing that:

1. Making a batchnode and adding those 2 images (pauseButton.png and playbutton.png) to sprite cash, so i can switch it via animation.
2. Recreating sprite

Code:

```
[_pauseButton removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
[_pauseButton release];
_pauseButton = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"playButton.png"] retain];
_pauseButton.position = ccp(_winSize.width * 0.92, _winSize.height * 0.1);
[self addChild:_pauseButton];
```

Are there any "proper" and easier ways to do this, or should I use 1 of those I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use a texture atlas you can use setDisplayFrame: to change what the sprite displays. That's the most efficient way.

Otherwise you'll have to use setTexture: to change the texture the sprite uses.

Answer (score -1):

The proper way of handling buttons in cocos2d is to use CCMenuItem. A tutorial on to do this can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle).

Comment: well i know, but there are certain situations when u need to switch sprite's image. Not only in button.

Comment: Ok, there was no way for me to know that. See the other answer from "LearningCocos2d", and if that answer help you then you should accept that answer.